# Objective C: Compare Array Element to String

Tags: iphone, objective-c, string, compare

Greetings,

I'm trying to simply compare a NSString to an NSArray.

Here is my code:

```
NSString *username=uname.text;
    NSString *regex=@"^[a-zA-Z0-9-_.]{3,20}$";
    NSArray *matchArray=nil;
    matchArray=[username componentsMatchedByRegex:regex];
    if(matchArray[0] == "asdf"){   //this line causes the problem!
        NSLog(@"matchArray %@",matchArray);
    }
```

I get an "invalid operands to binary ==" error.

How can I compare the string?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: What is in matchArray before if statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to compare an `NSString` to a C string (`char *`), which is wrong. `matchArray` is an `NSArray` so you cannot treat it as a C array either, you have to use its `objectAtIndex:` method and pass in the index.

Use this instead:

```
if ([[matchArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"asdf"]) {
    NSLog(@"matchArray %@", matchArray);
}
```

Addressing your comments, the reason why `isEqualToString:` does not show up in autocomplete is because Xcode cannot guess that `matchArray` contains `NSString`s (it only knows it contains `id`s, that is, arbitrary Objective-C objects). If you really wanted to be sure, you can perform an explicit cast, but it doesn't matter if you don't:

```
if ([(NSString *)[matchArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"asdf"]) {
    NSLog(@"matchArray %@", matchArray);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for that. It seems to be working now, although I'm getting NSExceptions being thrown now...

Comment: @Eamorr: Where, and what do they say?

Comment: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'. Think I need to check if array has a value before doing the if statement... Thanks!

Comment: @Eamorr: Yeah, other than that it should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

you want to use -objectAtIndex to get the array element. NOT the C array accessor syntax

Comment: Ok, I tried if([matchArray objectAtIndex:0) xxxxx @"asdf"), but what goes where the xxxxx is? isEqualToString doesn't show in the auto-complete... Many thanks,

Comment: `[[matchArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualTo: @"asd"]`

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

```
[[matchArray objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"asdf"];
```

anyway the string "asdf" should be @"asdf"

Comment: isEqualToString doesn't come up on the auto-complete ;(

Comment: try this one, with objectAtIndex

Comment: Hey, it's working now, once I surrounded it with square brackets